# ¿Cómo hago que pase a la siguiente pregunta?

Tags: python, tkinter

Espero me puedan ayudar, mi código sólo me muestra la primera pregunta y no pasa de ahí, no sé que este haciendo mal para que a la hora de presionar el botón de siguiente, pase a la siguiente pregunta y también quiero poner emoticones en lugar de las respuestas de satisfecho, muy satisfecho , etc...

Al parecer el problema es casi al final cuando meto la funcion restart, pero no sé bien, espero me puedan ayudar por favor.
Saludos

```
import tkinter as tk

class SatisfactionSurvey(tk.Toplevel):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        
        self.survey_questions = [
            "¿Cómo calificaría su experiencia general con nuestro servicio?",
            "¿Cómo calificaría la atención brindada por nuestro personal?",
            "¿Cómo calificaría la calidad de nuestros productos?",
            "¿Cómo calificaría la rapidez de entrega de nuestros productos?",
            "¿Volvería a utilizar nuestros servicios en el futuro?"
        ]
        self.current_question_index = 0
        self.show_current_question()
        
    def show_current_question(self):
        if self.current_question_index >= len(self.survey_questions):
            self.destroy()
            return
        
        self.question_label = tk.Label(self, text=self.survey_questions[self.current_question_index])
        self.question_label.pack()
        
        self.rating = tk.IntVar()
        tk.Radiobutton(self, text="Muy Insatisfecho", variable=self.rating, value=1).pack()
        tk.Radiobutton(self, text="Insatisfecho", variable=self.rating, value=2).pack()
        tk.Radiobutton(self, text="Neutral", variable=self.rating, value=3).pack()
        tk.Radiobutton(self, text="Satisfecho", variable=self.rating, value=4).pack()
        tk.Radiobutton(self, text="Muy Satisfecho", variable=self.rating, value=5).pack()
        
        self.submit_button = tk.Button(self, text="Siguiente", command=self.submit)
        self.submit_button.pack()
        
    def submit(self):
        rating = self.rating.get()
        self.current_question_index += 1
        
        if self.current_question_index >= len(self.survey_questions):
            self.question_label.destroy()
            self.submit_button.destroy()
    
            tk.Label(self, text="Gracias por participar en nuestras encuestas de satisfacción").pack()
            restart_button = tk.Button(self, text="Reiniciar", command=self.restart)
            restart_button.pack()
    
    def restart(self):
        self.destroy()
        SatisfactionSurvey().mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = SatisfactionSurvey()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: La parte de los emoticones te sugeriría eliminarla de tu pregunta y crear una nueva con lo que has intentado hacer para limitarla a un solo problema por publicación.

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia, soy nuevo y no se bien como usar la plataforma :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

**Nota:** Es importante que cada publicación tenga una sola pregunta, para que la respuesta pueda aplicarse a otros usuarios, por lo que responderé únicamente la parte de actualizar la pregunta y que puedas ver todas las que tienes en tu lista.

**Nota adicional:** El código actual muestra dos ventanas al iniciarse, desconozco si es el comportamiento deseado así que únicamente modifiqué la parte para actualizar la pregunta.

La razón por la que no funciona es porque te hace falta decirle a la etiqueta que cambie el valor actual por la nueva pregunta. Adentro de `submit` defines lo que debe suceder en caso de que el índice de la pregunta actual sea mayor o igual que el número de preguntas que tienes, pero no defines ninguna acción en caso de que aún queden preguntas en tu lista, por lo que te haría falta un `else` para poder actualizar el contenido de la etiqueta.

La etiqueta se puede actualizar de esta forma:

```
self.question_label.config(text = self.survey_questions[self.current_question_index])
```

Otro detalle es que los botones radiales deberían "limpiarse" para que el usuario pueda elegir alguna opción nueva y que no esté la elección de la pregunta anterior seleccionada. Esto lo puedes hacer al volver a hacer `0` la variable `self.rating`:

```
self.rating.set(0)
```

Otro punto importante de los botones radiales es que necesitan una variable para cada uno, esto te va a ayudar a que puedas eliminarlos cuando ya no queden preguntas, por ejemplo, para el primer botón radial:

```
self.rb1 = tk.Radiobutton(self, text="Muy Insatisfecho", variable=self.rating, value=1)
self.rb1.pack()
```

Y los tienes que destruir tal como haces con la etiqueta y el botón de "siguiente":

```
self.rb1.destroy()
```

Ejemplo completo:

```
import tkinter as tk

class SatisfactionSurvey(tk.Toplevel):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        
        self.survey_questions = [
            "¿Cómo calificaría su experiencia general con nuestro servicio?",
            "¿Cómo calificaría la atención brindada por nuestro personal?",
            "¿Cómo calificaría la calidad de nuestros productos?",
            "¿Cómo calificaría la rapidez de entrega de nuestros productos?",
            "¿Volvería a utilizar nuestros servicios en el futuro?"
        ]
        self.current_question_index = 0
        self.show_current_question()
        
    def show_current_question(self):
        if self.current_question_index >= len(self.survey_questions):
            self.destroy()
            return
        
        self.question_label = tk.Label(self, text=self.survey_questions[self.current_question_index])
        self.question_label.pack()
        
        self.rating = tk.IntVar()
        
        # Mostrar las opciones y asignarlas a un atributo de la clase
        self.rb1 = tk.Radiobutton(self, text="Muy Insatisfecho", variable=self.rating, value=1)
        self.rb1.pack()
        self.rb2 = tk.Radiobutton(self, text="Insatisfecho", variable=self.rating, value=2)
        self.rb2.pack()
        self.rb3 = tk.Radiobutton(self, text="Neutral", variable=self.rating, value=3)
        self.rb3.pack()
        self.rb4 = tk.Radiobutton(self, text="Satisfecho", variable=self.rating, value=4)
        self.rb4.pack()
        self.rb5 = tk.Radiobutton(self, text="Muy Satisfecho", variable=self.rating, value=5)
        self.rb5.pack()
        
        self.submit_button = tk.Button(self, text="Siguiente", command=self.submit)
        self.submit_button.pack()
        
    def submit(self):
        rating = self.rating.get()
        self.current_question_index += 1
        
        if self.current_question_index >= len(self.survey_questions):
            self.question_label.destroy()
            self.submit_button.destroy()
            # Destruir las opciones
            self.rb1.destroy()
            self.rb2.destroy()
            self.rb3.destroy()
            self.rb4.destroy()
            self.rb5.destroy()
    
            tk.Label(self, text="Gracias por participar en nuestras encuestas de satisfacción").pack()
            restart_button = tk.Button(self, text="Reiniciar", command=self.restart)
            restart_button.pack()
        
        # Actualizar la pregunta y el valor de rating
        else:
            self.question_label.config(text=self.survey_questions[self.current_question_index])
            self.rating.set(0)
    
    def restart(self):
        self.destroy()
        SatisfactionSurvey().mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = SatisfactionSurvey()
    app.mainloop()
```

**Sugerencia:** En el código actual todas las respuestas a tus preguntas están guardadas en la misma variable `self.rating`, esta se sobre escribe en cada nueva pregunta así que si tienes pensado procesar las respuestas al final, por ejemplo promediarlas, no vas a poder hacerlo. Te recomendaría crear una lista o un diccionario de respuestas según el número de preguntas que tengas. Esta parte **NO** la modifiqué porque desconozco lo que deseas hacer, pero es un punto que yo consideraría hacer.

Comment: ]Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, Sobre la nota adicional; es un error que me muestre las 2 ventanas como puedo hacer que solo muestre 1? y sobre la sugerencia; si voy a almacenar las respuestas en una base de datos, me podrías dar un ejemplo por favor?

Comment: Buen día @Bernardo, si la respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Para otras preguntas por favor crea publicaciones nuevas que contengan una sola pregunta por publicación y no olvides incluir lo que has intentado y los errores que te impiden obtener el resultado deseado. Saludos

Comment: listo, entonces pondré en otras preguntas lo demás.